# R Replace stopwords in a column made of lists

Tags: r, apply

Considering this data frame

```
test = data.frame(language=c("german", "english"), text=I(list(c("und das Beil", "wichtige Thematik der"), c("some useful information", "the most unuseful product"))))
```

I need to delete the stopwords in each vector of column "text" according to which language the row belongs. Actually, I only need to differ between german and english, so I thought of using apply in combination with ifelse like this:

```
test[2] = apply(test, 1, function(x) ifelse(x[1] == "german", lapply(x[2], function(y)removeWords(y, stopwords("de"))), lapply(x[2], function(y)removeWords(y, stopwords("en")))))
```

But this doesn´t work..
Maybe there is even an more elegant way to solve this?

Comment: what is the desired output for your test data?

Comment: The output should be in the form that I can replace the column 'text'. It should be a vector (or list?) in which each entry is a list.

Answer (score 0):

As a first step you could do:

`library(tm)`

`apply(test, 1, function(x) removeWords(x[["text"]], stopwords(x[["language"]])))`

Which gives you as a result:

```
     [,1]                 [,2]                 
[1,] "  Beil"             " useful information"
[2,] "wichtige Thematik " "  unuseful product"
```

I dont know what the desired output is though...

Comment: The output must have the same structure like the column 'text', so that I can replace it. Is it possible that I can define my own lists of stopwords (e.g. stopwordsDE and stopwordsEN) in this solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tidy solution that can easily be extended to multiple languages:

```
library(tidyverse)

test <- tibble(
  language = c("german", "english"), 
  text = I(list(c("und das Beil", "wichtige Thematik der"), 
                c("some useful information", "the most unuseful product")))
)

test %>%
  mutate(lang_abr = recode(language, "german" = "de", "english" = "en")) %>%
  mutate(text = map2(text, lang_abr, ~ removeWords(.x, stopwords(.y))))
```